# Csv encoding when loading in BigQuery Google

Tags: mongodb, csv, google-bigquery

But unfortunately I have the following loading error when trying to load the previously created csv:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "mongodb111.py", line 38, in <module>
df.to_csv(csv_file, index=False, encoding='utf-8')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3020, in to_csv
formatter.save()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py", line 172, in save
self._save()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py", line 274, in _save
self._save_header()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py", line 242, in _save_header
writer.writerow(encoded_labels)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 595, in writerow
self.stream.write(data)
TypeError: unicode argument expected, got 'str'
```

I am trying to load some data from MongoDB into BigQuery with the following code:

```
    ........
    data = []
    for document in collection.find():
        #print(document["_id"])
        document["_id"] = str(document["_id"])
        data.append([document["_id"], document["account_id"], document["limit"], document["products"]])

   
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["_id", "account_id", "limit", "products"])
    
    csv_file = io.StringIO()
    df.to_csv(csv_file, index=False, encoding='utf-8')
    csv_file.seek(0)
    
    
    bigquery_client.load_table_from_file(csv_file, table).result()
    
    client.close()
    client_bq.close()
```

Has anyone encountered this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using python 2.7.
Using python 3 should solve the issue.

—-
Why not use `bigquery_client.load_table_from_dataframe(df, table)` directly instead of creating a csv file and using `bigquery_client.load_table_from_file`?